# Appsheet Dropdown Source From Google Sheet

Tags: google-appsheet

I am new to Google Appsheet and facing below issue. Before posting the issue I checked for solution in the community but could not find it hence, posting a question over here.

I want to create a drop-down list in app-sheet i.e. Enum and want to give google sheet column reference as a data source in the drop-down list of the appsheet so whenever I update the list in google sheet the drop-down list in the appsheet is automatically updated.

Any help on above will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solution on above found, this can be done by using the table reference concept i.e. in place of using Enum for the particular column have to use reference concept and then have to provide the reference of the source of the table from where the data is to be used.